# converting apache 2.2 to apache 2.4 ldap authentication

Tags: apache, ldap

I've had this configuration working fine for many years on Apache 2.2. A recent patch/upgrade cycle has moved us to apache 2.4. Now it isn't working.

I've installed mod_ldap with

> yum install mod_ldap -y

My apache config is (I've removed the vital stuff with xxx):

`AuthBasicAuthoritative  off
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter your name"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://myldap.server/ou=People,ou=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx?sAMAccountName,cn,DN,displayName?sub?"
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=myaccount,OU=_Service Accounts,OU=Managed Linux,OU=Servers,DC=xx,DC=xx"
AuthLDAPBindPassword xxxxxxxxx
AuthGroupFile  /usr/local/apache/passwd/groups
require group Admins
AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute sAMAccountName`

In the error logs, it gives the message:

AH01796: AuthType Basic configured without corresponding module

However the AuthBasic module is loaded in the config:

LoadModule auth_basic_module lib/modules/mod_auth_basic.so

So I'm not sure what is causing the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I turned up logging to debug level and could see it was the connection to the ldap server. The message wasn't descriptive, just that the connection was dropped. After a bit of looking around I discovered it was that Apache wasn't correctly pointed to the CA certs directory. Fixed the Cert path, and then it worked. Hope this helps the next person stuck with this issue.